# Filters on finite sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

This is question I saw in Topology Course.

Let X be a non-empty finite set. Construct all filters on X.

Actually, I know the definition of filters on sets, but I don't how to construct them, and I don't really know what it is meant to constrcuct.

Answer (score 1):

A filter $\mathcal{F}$ is a subset of all subsets of $X$. So if $X$ is finite, so is $\mathscr{P}(X)$ and so is $\mathcal{F}$. A filter is closed under finite intersections so $A:=\bigcap \mathcal{F}$ is a (non-empty!) member of the filter $\mathcal{F}$ too. The enlargement axiom then implies that $\mathcal{F}= \mathcal{F}_A:= \{B \subseteq X: A \subseteq B\}$.

So all filters on $X$ are just the sets of supersets of a fixed non-empty subset $A$ of $X$. So quite boring.